# i would like to divide two colums in Bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I would like is possible to divide the column A by the column B as column C, in Bigquery.

For example `SELECT prix / surface as prixmcarre FROM 'appartement'`, is not possible in bigquery.

Error: `No matching signature for operator / for argument types: STRING, STRING. Supported signatures: FLOAT64 / FLOAT64; NUMERIC / NUMERIC at [1:8]`

In the Google Cloud Document, I don't see the simple solution.

Thank's for your help :)

Comment: You are trying to divide strings - but you can only divide numbers. You can try to SAFE_CAST() the strings to numbers

Answer (score 2):

You must be using strings that look like integers or floats. You need to cast them. For example:

```
select cast('10' as INT64) / cast('5' as INT64)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply. My table has 100000 lines, how can I make sure to apply the formula on all lines? Is possible in Bigquery ?

Comment: The formula will be apply per your where condition so yes it can be applied on all rows in the table